# Tkinter : How to Dynamically adjust the content according to the desired Display size [Issue caused by pyautogui]

Tags: tkinter

I have a working tkinter application and sometimes I have to run it on a ****bigger display** size(55 inch screen in my case**) but the  widgets are not adjusted according to the display size.

Earlier, I was under the impression that I might have missed something because of which the widgets are not aligned according to the display size but, after further investigation I found **pyautogui** import was the culprit.  You can test using the code below  to understand the issue better

**You may not notice this issue on Laptop screen but if you will run the same code on bigger display than your laptop , you will see the difference.**

First - Comment the pyautogui import and run the code, you will see Normal size of progress bar. [image: Without_pyautogui_import]

Second : Uncomment the pyautogui and run the code, you will see progress bar size has been reduced a lot. [image: Image_after_import_pyautogui]

In this example, I have used only  the progress bar to recreate the issue but if you have screen filled with all the widgets , you will see huge a gap between widgets which are not aligned properly.

Weird thing is, I have not even created the object for pyautogui, import is enough to mess up the widgets.
Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pyautogui

tk=Tk()
progress=Progressbar(tk,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode='determinate')

def bar():
    import time
    progress['value']=20
    tk.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    progress['value']=50
    tk.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    progress['value']=80
    tk.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    progress['value']=100

progress.pack()
Button(tk,text='foo',command=bar).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. In a nutshell, it boils down to a good design and making use of the features of `pack` and `grid`. Without know more details about your specific problem, we can't give better advice.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated my question and also found the issue. Please see and let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible pyautogui is using the name `tk` during it's construction, and it's overwriting expected default values; probably during initialization of PyMsgBox.  I'd avoid that keyword and try `root` as your root window name instead, as that tends to be acceptable practice in many tkinter examples I've seen.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
##  import pyautogui

title = 'Progressbar'
root = Tk() ; root .title( title )
root .bind( '<Escape>',  lambda e: root .destroy() )

'''
root .attributes( '-zoomed',  True )
root .update_idletasks()
Width, Height = root .winfo_width(),  root .winfo_height()
'''

##  Might have better results by specifying windowsize
Width, Height = 600, 400
root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}' )

progress = Progressbar( root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='determinate' )

def bar():
    import time
    progress['value'] = 20
    root .update_idletasks()
    time .sleep(1)
    progress['value'] = 50
    root .update_idletasks()
    time .sleep(1)
    progress['value'] = 80
    root .update_idletasks()
    time .sleep(1)
    progress['value'] = 100

progress .pack()
Button( root, text='foo', command=bar ) .pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, In my actual application , I am using rootwin instead of tk while creating the instance of Tk(). I copied this from stackoverflow just to give an idea about the problem. I didn't realize instance name was tk. But, you can use any name for instance creation, problem still persists.I am new to python and tkinter but simple import won't construct anything unless you create the object. please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, well did you try specifying a windowsize, or is it just picking whatever pixel-width is convenient for the display?

Comment: Yes, I have window size defined.

Comment: Still not certain.  Not seeing any value changed that I expected to see.  `print( vars( progress ), '\n\n', progress .config(), '\n\n', tk .config() )`  You're running on current versions of those modules?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, You won't see the difference on laptop but if you run it on bigger display you will see the changes. It works just fine on laptop screen 1368*768 whether you have pyautogui imported or not. I am not sure if you've tested it on laptop on bigger screen. if it was on laptop then you won't see that behavior I was talking about.